# Design a Discrete-Time System

Tags: discrete-signals

Could you help me with this theoretical question.

The purpose is to design a discrete-time system. What it does is, it finds the maximum value in a one-dimensional sequence whose elements consist only of "non-negative" real numbers and contains only a single global maximum with no local maxima.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you have a set of positive numbers and you need to write an algorithm to find the max in that set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have defined your signal $x[n]$ to be a set of non-negative numbers with a single global maxima, the algorithm to find the maximum is quite simple.

compute the first (causal , backward) difference 
$$y[n] = x[n] - x[n-1]$$

Then look for the sign change of $y[n]$; i.e., at the extreme point you will have the sign of $y[n]$ changing from positive to negative,  assuming you had a single global maxima.

$$z[n] = \text{sign_change_detector} \{ y[n] \} $$

Don't forget to check the end points as well. As they are also the candidates to be maximum in addition to those critical point(s).